# How feasible would it be if cockroaches no bigger than an inch (2.5 centimetres) took fall damage from around 6-7 feet in the air or less?

Tags: science-based, biology, physics, death, insects

Ok, so I have an unfinished/W.I.P world (may turn it into story) about a sapient civilization of cockroaches called Roachins that are pretty much German Cockroachs, but most/many can fly and can stand on 2 legs and use their 1st and 2nd set of legs like we use our arms.

Anyway, they have pretty much the same tech as modern humans have, vehicles like cars, helicopters, and ships. Also tools like ladders and the like.

Now, irl, most roaches are good or decent runners and fliers, and can swim to an acceptable level. I handwaved it by saying that at least a certain country of Roachins got too 'domesticated'(human-like), and now they cannot run as fast, fly as well, or swim as well. This has also effected their climbing abilities.

Basically, I got to thinking about how some insects and spiders take damage from falling like tarantulas and big beetles, while most/many do not because of their size or build, and thought that having this group of Roachins take fall damage because they kind of got a  bit fatter for their size, and maybe their exoskeleton a bit weaker, would be an interesting touch.

So, could a Roachin from this country feasibly take fall damage without having to fall like from something like a human scale skyscraper? Maybe more so a Roachin scale skyscraper, so like 6-7 (maybe 8) feet fall. Would it kill or at least hurt them badly?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144937/discussion-on-question-by-conan-highwoods-how-feasible-would-it-be-if-cockroache); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 20):

Small creatures do not get damaged from falling because they quickly reach terminal velocity and thus do not hit that hard on the ground.

The only way to get away from this and get falling damage is to either make the falling thing more chubby, therefore having more mass will also have higher terminal velocity (which would be in line with being domesticated and therefore less lean), or to make so that the landing happens on an unfortunate configuration; think of landing joint first or not using any protective reflex (like a man stumbling and not using their hands to protect their head).

Comment: Or reduce air pressure so terminal velocity is higher...

Comment: doesn't help from that height unless gravity is a lot higher as well. after falling 2m you just have a speed of 6m/s even in a vacuum.

Comment: @ths 6 m/s could cause injury to a weak, unprepared human so it could cause injury to a weak, unprepared cockroach. There's a misconception that smaller animals can handle falls better because of the square-cube law. Nope; the scaling factors actually cancel out. Bigger animal is weaker but also has longer legs to absorb the impact gradually. It's only air resistance that helps smaller animals handle higher falls. The converse of falling is jumping, and tigers jump higher than house cats. (in meters, not relative to body length). http://web.mit.edu/6.055/old/S2009/notes/jump-heights.pdf

Comment: A detail to consider is that the damage from a fall is due to the relationship between the materials the animal is made from (chitin, muscles, bone etc.) and the forces acting on the body at the fall. During scale-up the mass/force increases much faster than any strengthening of the base materials, resulting in horrific injury if an elephant tips over, and a flea withstanding 100 G's when it jumps.

Comment: Even humans can easily survive a 2m fall mostly if not entirely unharmed, unless they land on their head or something.  A creature the size of an insect won't be even remotely harmed by such a fall, even without air resistance slowing their fall.

Comment: Or you could reduce the air density, acceleration in a vacuum does not fall off.

Comment: @causative the role of the square-cube law isn't a misconception here.  It's directly relevant to *why* air resistance helps smaller creatures more than larger creatures.

Comment: @causative is broadly correct about the square-cube law: The *toughness* of a material is how much energy *per unit volume* it can absorb before damage. For an impact of a given velocity (or a given fall height in a vacuum chamber), the energy per volume does not change with scaling.

But a human 2 meter fall (the feet start 2 meters above the ground) is actually a 3 meter fall: in order to absorb the energy you "crumple" and end up low to the ground; your *center of mass* falls a greater distance. So it is somewhat harder on larger animals.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman re "can survive..." --> ... often ...." . I've fallen essentially flat on my back from under 2 metres (due to complex circumstances) and may well have suffered major injury if I had not punched through a fibroliote deck with one leg. It still did some spinal cord damage (also complex). I've been pushed over backwards (or maybe hit - brain does not say)) and fell backwards and sturck a steel sign post part way down and broke my rh collar bone AND my right big toe :-) !.  || Long ago I slipped and slid down a mild sandbank while hiking. No pain, no problem - ...

Comment: ... until I tried to stand up.  I broke the small bone on the outer side of my right foot. Pain ot correlated well with size :-). || I fell full length on my knee on a gym rebounder and broke the knee cap.|| _ ... :-) || I'm 72. Not vastly risk prone but a bit more gingho that some. Makes for an interesting life. ||(Two car vs motorcycle accidents wee at about 1 metre up BUT there were other energy sources :-).

Comment: @RussellMcMahon I said "can", not "always will".  Certainly a shorter fall can still cause serious, even fatal injury, particularly to people who weren't in great shape to begin with, but 2m is still well within the survivability range for a reasonably fit human.  And something as small as an insect would barely even feel it.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Noted. For completeness - neither the damage from my on-the-back nor signpost falls were liable to be substantially affected by fitness. Energy from a 2m x 80 kg (me) fall is about 1600 Joule. How it gets distributed affects effect. Air drag is under ~= 10N (1 kg) at impact (at sea level on earth at STP).

Answer (score 16):

**Not feasible**

Even if you scale them up to the size of a mouse, terminal velocity is only about 15 m/s, which is generally survivable by all but the most fragile creatures, especially since the squared-cubed rule makes smaller creatures proportionally stronger.  Rule of thumb provided [here](https://www.understandinganimalresearch.org.uk/what-is-animal-research/a-z-animals/rat/rat-10-facts#:%7E:text=Terminal%20velocity%20for%20animals%20is,human%27s%20%7E50%20m%2Fs.) is that:

> Terminal velocity for animals is approximately 90 d0.5 m/s, where d is
> the diameter of the animal in meters.

The only way to make a creature that size take damage from any conceivable falling distance is to have it fall on a very delicate body structure while unconscious (as per the answer by L.Dutch), or to fall onto a dangerous chemical or electrified surface.  With even vestigial flying ability, an out-of-condition, office-working cockroach will still be able to land on its feet without taking damage.

Comment: "Especially since the square-cube law makes smaller creatures proportionally stronger" - not for falls. The smaller creature is proportionally stronger but also their body is able to deform proportionally less before taking damage. As a result the velocity at which you are injured upon hitting a hard surface is fairly independent of your size. It's only air resistance that protects the cockroach. See http://web.mit.edu/6.055/old/S2009/notes/jump-heights.pdf for jump height, which scales the same way as fall height.

Comment: @causative I disagree. Just look at what would happen to an upscaled human. He would crush his own bones with his weight just by standing (due to the square-cube law). Falling even small distances would be devestating for the giant. Smaller creatures are much sturdier in comparsion to their body size.

Comment: @causative I cannot see how these jumps translate into dangers of accidental falls. A cat can fall from high and land relatively safely given that it will land on its feet but a tiger will just smash because its limbs cannot take the impact.

Comment: @datacube no. Read the pdf. Falling is jumping in reverse.

Comment: @JaniMiettinen That's because of air resistance, and in fact despite urban legend domestic cats can be severely injured from multi story falls. https://pets.webmd.com/cats/guide/cat-high-rise-syndrome

Comment: @causative that is only true for proper nad complete damageless landing (landing feet first and absorbing all the fall energy into muscle movement). 
Edit: The remaining energy is then is transferred into deformation energy, which will then range from a "bit pain" to "breaking bones or exosceleton" depending on the amount of Energy left and the sturdyness of the bodyparts.

Comment: @datacube It's true for falling badly as well because the larger creature exerts less force per unit mass but exerts that force over a proportionally longer distance before he gets hurt. The fall energy that must be dissipated per unit mass is also invariant with size.

Comment: @causative There is a crucial difference: domestic cat CAN be severely injured, but tiger WILL be smashed. Jumping and landing in a controllable fashion only pertains to heights that stay way below what this question is about.

Comment: @JaniMiettinen Air resistance is why the tiger would be smashed. A tiger can jump 15 ft vertically so it can certainly fall a couple stories without injury if it lands properly, which is already a distance that can injure a domestic cat. Above that air resistance starts to dominate. Also, the question is about a 6ft drop, which is less than 15. You're thinking about the height of drop in proportion to the animal, but that's not what is invariant. What's invariant is the height of drop in absolute terms when neglecting air resistance.

Comment: @causative Sure, but the question is about accidental falling, not controlled jumping and landing. Tiger can definitely sustain a fall you are talking about IF it lands on its feet, but so can cockroaches, too. But a tiger will be injured severely if it landed on its back while cockroach landing on its back will still be just fine.

Comment: A cockroach, falling back first from 2 m in a vacuum chamber onto a smooth stone surface, may very well get injured. Of course, it doesn't have a vulnerable spinal cord.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, pretty much the same as everyone else has said ─ insects and other surface-heavy animals barely take damage from falling at all. [cockroachzone.com](https://cockroachzone.com) notes that "Cockroaches don't get injured, let alone die, from falling [...] irrespective of the height they fall from."

If the cockroaches were larger, or had a lower surface area, they could conceivably take some falling damage, but not significantly. Also, it may be relevant that adult cockroaches can glide/fly for short distances.